# undefined method `microposts' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am reading Michal Hart's tutorial and working on Rails 4. I spent hours sorting out this problem.

user_controller.erb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def show
    @user = current_user
    @microposts = @user.microposts
  end
end
```

micopost_controller.erb:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController



 def create
    @micropost = Micropost.create(micropost_params)

  end

  private
  def micropost_params
    params.require(:micropost).permit(:content) if params[:micropost]

  end

end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<h2>Users Post</h2>
<% if @user.microposts.any? %>
    <table class="microposts" summary="User microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
    </table>
```

_micropost.html.erb:

```
<tr>
<td class="micropost">
        <span class="content">
            <%= micropost.content %>
        </span>
        <span class="timestamp">
            Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Even "[undefined method `microposts'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116176/undefined-method-microposts)" could not help me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may need to create a micropost and save it?

Comment: `@user = current_user # this is returning nil`

Comment: Let's see your `current_user` method.

Comment: @VIDYA: I USED gem 'devise'. Anything I can show plz let me know.. i m struggling.

Comment: Hear galloping think horses not zebras. When you started the app, did you log in as a user?

Comment: @Philip : I am not to that point where I log in as a user, post and display it. As of now, I am just trying to display post saved via console.

Comment: I'm not sure the caps help you out here, @SHANKAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@user = current_user # this is returning nil
```

The error "undefined method 'foo' for nil:NilClass" means:

*"Hey, somewhere you wrote blahblahblah.foo, but the value of `blahblahblah` is `nil`, which does not have a `foo` method."*

In this case, the only time you ever call `.microposts` is `@user.microposts`, which means that `@user` is `nil`. We see that it gets assigned the result of `current_user`, so that method is returning `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Some debugging things to try:

You're going to want to make sure you have the correct models created (and post them as well.) Make sure that inside said models you have the associations correctly defined (micropost belongs_to user, user has_many microposts)

After that, make sure that you have the associated database entries created using rake db:migrate, and note this will require a restart of your server to really get working.

Print the current_user to the console a few times, and see if it's rendering properly. `pp` works great for things like that (pretty print, you'll love it for JSON and other types of data.)

Without having more information though, that's as much as I can really give you.

Comment: I have associations defined correctly since I am very new in ROR, I know less debugging techniques but still I m trying. Thank you though.